# Svelte - easy way to inherit from sveltestrap component?

Tags: svelte

I'm trying out Svelte for the first time and I'm wanting to do something like below. Where I take a button from an existing component library and just add a single parameter to it. I'd like to be able to still have access to all the sveltestrap options from original button. Or is this not possible in Svelte?

```
<script lang="ts">
    import { Button, Spinner } from 'sveltestrap';
    export let loading = false;
</script>

<Button>
    {#if loading }
        <Spinner />
    {:else}
        <slot/>
    {/if}
</Button>
```

Answer (score 3):

The closest thing is probably spreading [`$$restProps`](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-attributes-and-props) and forwarding the events that are of interest (there currently is no method of just forwarding all).

```html
<script lang="ts">
    import { Button, Spinner } from 'sveltestrap';
    export let loading = false;
</script>

<Button {...$$restProps} on:click > <!-- add more events as needed -->
    {#if loading }
        <Spinner />
    {:else}
        <slot/>
    {/if}
</Button>
```

[REPL example](https://svelte.dev/repl/d7f212c6d8654057bf8c8b0065112b26?version=3.48.0)